# npm install quick.db takes forever

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I am trying to install quick.db, and I keep getting stuck on the line below.

I have tried npm rebuild, I have tried reinstalling node, but nothing is working. I have waited for about 3 hours.

I am using a Linux server from the free tier on Google Cloud. And I am using quick.db for a discordjs bot.

```
make: Entering directory '/home/user/discordbot/app/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
  TOUCH b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_locate_sqlite3_target_extract_sqlite3 b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/locate_sqlite3.stamp
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.o
```

Comment: I believe your issue is related to better-sqlite3 installation

Comment: I know, but even when I try to install better-sqlite3 on its own, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with Google Cloud's processing because you're overloading it with npm packages. Seeing as this seems like an issue with better-sqlite3, try to uninstall all your npm packages with `npm uninstall` and getting rid of `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and reload everything back in. Additionally, get rid of any packages you may not be using.

If that fails, you can try link node.js to `/usr/bin/node` in terminal with `sudo ln -s "$(version of node you're using)" /usr/bin/node`